# Eclipse will not stop at breakpoint and puts thread state into Running: User Request

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, breakpoints, archlinux

Recently, Eclipse SDK decided to kill my brain cells.

Out of the blue, it just stopped pausing at breakpoints. I do see it hit the breakpoint, but right then window loses focus and in the thread/callstack window it shows

```
MyApp [C/C++ Application]
  MyApp [18556][cores:1]
    Thread [2] (Running : Container)
    Thread [1] (Running : User Request)
  gdb
```

I see when i hits my breakpoint and it takes a blink of an eye before it goes into above state. My app stops responding and working and i have to kill it.

My app is a non GUI application which runs in linux as a background task, it reads and writes files, performs communication through COM and TCP/UDP. No user input is ever requested or anything like that.

There are tons of people who have problems with eclipse having problems with breakpoints, however they all are about java projects and or windows version of eclipse and none of the provided solutions work for me.

So far i have:

Rebuilt index.
Cleaned and rebuild project.
Deleted all debug files, makefile, binary and built again.
Cleared all breakpoints.
Made sure it was not set to ignore breakpoints.

and probably more which i already forgot.

Eclipse version is 4.2.1
Linux: Arch linux which was not updated for like 2 years now.
Project is C++.

What other information do i need to provide?
  How can i solve this problem. I can't debug my application :(

Comment: I assume the configuration is set to Debug, right?

Comment: It sure is, i double, triple and quadruple check that it also takes the Debug/MyApp binary when running.

Comment: I seem to be able to use breakpoints after i have changed the debugger (or launcher, don't quite understand this part yet). I have always been using `GDB (DSF) Create process launcher`, now i selected `Standard Create process launcher` with a debuffer `gdb/mi`. This, however doesn't solve my primary problem, as this debugger seems to be too basic and won't show much stuff while debugging. At this point i am using this as i don't have any other options.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem in this way: "Run" -> "Debug Configuration" -> select you configuration -> Debugger.
Then check the checkbox which shows "Use external console for inferior (open a new console window for input/output)".